# Parse mode does not work when copying a message(AIOGRAM)

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, telegram-bot, aiogram

I want to make a post function in the bot using copy_to. The documentation indicates that there is parse_mode in the copy_to method, but it does not work for me

This is my code

```
    with sqlite3.connect('********.db') as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        info_about_ids = cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM users")
        con.commit()
    list_of_chats = [i[3] for i in info_about_ids.fetchall()]
    print(list_of_chats)
    for i in list_of_chats:
        try:
            await mess.copy_to(chat_id=i, parse_mode='html')
            print('Good way!')
        except:
            print('Bad way')
    await state.finish()
```

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsREK.png)